# Aligning a figure and table side by side

Tags: tables, subfloats

I would like to place a figure side-by-side with a table, and have both of them aligned to the top. This is what I came up with:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.65\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{3_comparative/fig/pic.pdf}
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[t]{0.35\linewidth}
      \begin{tabular}{| c | c |}
        \hline
        Contrast & value \\
        \hline
        I & 6 \\
        ... \\
        \hline
      \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Phylogenetic independent contrasts}
\end{figure}
```

But this doesn't work as I hoped, the two items are misaligned:
[image: Rendered figure and table]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 18):

The answer to this common question is to be found in
[Keith Reckdahl's epslatex.pdf](ftp://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/info/epslatex.pdf), page 36, "Minipage Vertical Alignment".
I quote the particular solution here. Please note the "secret", the two `\vspace{0pt}`

```
\begin{center}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1in]{graphic}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t]{.25\linewidth}
\vspace{0pt}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=1in,angle=-45]{graphic}
\end{minipage}
\end{center}
```

In general, this document is a must for any LaTeX work with graphics.

/Leif Andersson

Comment: Most enlightening!

Comment: Thank you very much! Also works if you try to have text and a table side-by-side too.

Comment: Needs an end } after \end{center Apparently I can't edit only a single character.