# Figure and table side by side with common caption

Tags: floats, positioning, captions, vertical-alignment

I'm not a LaTeX expert, and I want to align a table and a figure side by side, with a common caption; the table and the figure should be aligned to the bottom, too.

I tried this:

```
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.60\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6cm}{6cm} %to simulate an actual figure
  \end{minipage}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Zzzzzz} \\
  \hline \hline
  A & B &  C \\ \hline
  0 & 0 &  0\\ \hline
  0 & 1 &  0\\ \hline
  1 & 0 &  0\\ \hline
  1 & 1 &  1\\ \hline%
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Bla bla}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

But the result is:

```
*********
*********
*********
*********   Zzzzz
*********   0 0 0
*********   0 0 1
            0 1 0
            0 1 1
            1 1 1

 Figure 1: Bla bla
```

The table and the figure are not bottom-aligned.
I read other answers on tex.stackexchange, but I didn't find a way to fix it.

Comment: What should the caption common to the two environments look like? E.g., do you want it to like `Figure and Table x: <Saption text>`, where `x` is the current value of the counter associated with the `figureandtable` environment?

Comment: @Mico: no, I need only to reference the figure ( Figure X: bla bla)

Comment: Nobody has given you the formal welcome yet. So [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image]

Pass the `b` option to your `tabular` environment, too. BTW, Please consider always adding a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. I have converted your code snippet into a MWE here.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.60\linewidth}
    \centering
    %\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
    \rule{6cm}{6cm} %to simulate an actual figure
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
    \centering
\begin{tabular}[b]{ |l|l|l| }
  \hline
  \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Zzzzzz} \\
  \hline \hline
  A & B &  C \\ \hline
  0 & 0 &  0\\ \hline
  0 & 1 &  0\\ \hline
  1 & 0 &  0\\ \hline
  1 & 1 &  1\\ \hline%
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Bla bla}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

Similarly to [Aligning a figure and table side by side](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/66109/21591) where the alignment is on top, you need a little trick here:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.60\linewidth}
    \centering
    \rule{6cm}{6cm} %to simulate an actual figure
    \par\vspace{0pt}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}[b]{0.30\linewidth}
    \centering%
    \begin{tabular}{ |l|l|l| }%
      \hline%
      \multicolumn{3}{|c|}{Zzzzzz} \\%
      \hline \hline
      A & B &  C \\ \hline%
      0 & 0 &  0\\ \hline%
      0 & 1 &  0\\ \hline%
      1 & 0 &  0\\ \hline%
      1 & 1 &  1\\ \hline%
    \end{tabular}%
    \par\vspace{0pt}
  \end{minipage}
\caption{Bla bla}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Notice the `\par\vspace{0pt}` at the end of the minipages. The trick is taken from [epslatex.pdf](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/epslatex.pdf), Section 11.4.1, where the misinterpretation of the `[b]` parameter of minipages is explained.