# Sequentially arrange multi-page side by side figures

Tags: graphics, subfloats, minipage, floatrow

I have many images to display on multiple pages, with 4 rows of 2 images side by side (total 8) per page.

However, I do not want the images at the last page (sometimes <4 rows) to be centered, but ordering from top to bottom. This is done by specifying `\begin{figure}[ht]`.

Code for first 2 images (and repeats for another 5 times for the total 7 rows):

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{floatrow}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{figure}[ht] 
\begin{floatrow} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} 
\includegraphics[width=120pt]{image1.pdf} 
\end{minipage} \hspace{-55pt} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}\vspace{20pt} 
\includegraphics[width=370pt]{image2.pdf}
\newline 
\vspace{-50pt} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{floatrow} 
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht] 
\begin{floatrow} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.4\linewidth} 
\includegraphics[width=120pt]{image3.pdf} 
\end{minipage} 
\hspace{-55pt} 
\begin{minipage}[t]{0.8\linewidth}\vspace{20pt} 
\includegraphics[width=370pt]{image4.pdf}
\newline 
\vspace{-50pt} 
\end{minipage} 
\end{floatrow} 
\end{figure}
```

But the resultant images are not arranged correctly, with only 3 images being on the 1st page and 4 on the second:

[image]

The desired output is to occupy pages fully (4 images first page), and then occupy from top to bottom in the subsequent page, if there is less than 4 images left:

[image]

Comment: Could you please make your example code compilable by adding the documentclass as well as the *relevant*  packages? See also: [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Please also specify if the images will have captions. Also, why do you use a floating environment like `figure`  if you aparently don't want your images to move around?

Comment: @leandriis I have editted to add the document class and packages used for the example. I use the floating environment to include and align all elements (images, table and caption, with the last two not included in this MWE) in the rows.

Comment: Why not simply use something like `\noindent
\includegraphics[width=0.225\textwidth]{image1.pdf}%
\hfill%
\includegraphics[width=0.725\textwidth]{image2.pdf}
\bigskip` completely without the `figure` environments? You can use `\captionof` from the `caption` package to add a caption. If this does not siut your needs regarding the not shown table and captions, please edit your question to also include information on the desired output and alignment of thouse elements.

Comment: Thank you for the simpler fix. With this information and the help from another post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66109/aligning-a-figure-and-table-side-by-side I was able to solve the more complex example of my code with additional tables.

Comment: The is no limit on how many [p] floats will go on a page.  You should also see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat/39020?r=SearchResults&s=1|0.0000#39020

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You not provide any information about your document.
- The sum of width of `minipage`s in one row is bigger than text width. This cause problems to placements figure on page.
- instead of `float` rows and `minipage`s I would rather use `tabular` at least for each row with figures:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\setcounter{totalnumber}{4}         % 2 may work better
\renewcommand{\textfraction}{0.05}  % allow minimal text w. figs


\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep} 
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image1.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image2.pdf} 
\end{tabular}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image3.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image4.pdf}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image5.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image6.pdf}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image7.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image8.pdf}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

\clearpage
\begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image9.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image10.pdf}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image7.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image11.pdf}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[h]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image9.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image12.pdf}
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

- it is not clear why you like to have each figures pair as standalone float. You should consider to  merge four or more rows with figures into one float:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep} 
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image1.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image2.pdf}    \\
\includegraphics{image3.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image4.pdf}    \\
\includegraphics{image5.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image6.pdf}    \\
\includegraphics{image7.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image8.pdf}    
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}

\begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep}
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image9.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image10.pdf}   \\
\includegraphics{image7.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image11.pdf}   \\
\includegraphics{image9.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image12.pdf}   \\
\end{tabular}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

If you like to ad captions to your figure, than you need to put in separate table row. For example like this:

```
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \setkeys{Gin}{width=\linewidth}
\begin{tabular}{@{} p{\dimexpr0.25\linewidth-\tabcolsep} 
                    p{\dimexpr0.75\linewidth-\tabcolsep} @{}}
\includegraphics{image1.pdf}
    &   \includegraphics{image2.pdf}    \\
\caption{figure 1}
    &   \caption{figure 2}              \\
% rest of float's body
```